# Configurar o charset do banco pelo arquivo de conexão

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, codificação-de-caracteres

Fiz a migração do PHP 5.5 para o 7.4, para isso instalei o sistema em uma nova maquina.
Após essa migração os dados que são retornados do banco vinham de forma diferente da versão anterior. Analisando observei que esses dados estavam vindo como utf-8, sendo que todo o restante do sistema é em iso 8859-1.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisando vi que é possível alterar a forma que o banco de dados envia os dados através do arquivo de conexão utilizando o PDO, porém somente para o SGBD MySQL.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=BANCO;charset=utf-8', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA');
$conn->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer algo semelhante para o SQL SERVER?

Comment: Qual driver você usa para acessar o SQL Server via PHP? E qual o sistema operacional do servidor PHP?

Comment: E também, qual collation está sendo usada nas tabelas do banco? E qual o tipo das colunas de texto? Varchar? Nvarchar?

Comment: Estou usando o pdo_sqlsrv para acessar o banco, o SO é o Ubuntu 20.04, collation estou usando 'Latin1_General_CI_AS' e os tipos de coluna são varchar.

Answer (score -1):

O problema estava no driver em que eu estava fazendo a conexão, rodei o seguinte comando para instalar um driver que estava faltando.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-pdo-dbli
```

Após a instalação desse driver alterei parte do código que fazia a conexão.

De

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=".$_HOST1 .";Database=".$_DB1,$_USER1,$_PASS1);
```

Para

```
$pdo = new PDO ("dblib:host=$_HOST1;dbname=$_DB1","$_USER1","$_PASS1");
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).